# How to upgrade Git on Raspberry Pi

Tags: git, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi-3 (RPi3) attached to a meter.  The RPi3 has firmware that runs on the meter.
Currently I have Git v2.1.4 installed on my RPi3.  Want to check if a newer version of Git is available, and if so, upgrade Git to the latest version.  Treading lightly so as not to download something unexpected, introduce incompatibility, and break my code!

Searching for how to update Git, I found that Google gets tripped-up and finds matches for how to look for changes to GitHub code base and download any changes to the code base from GitHub.

Comment: apt get update && apt get upgrade? Could help if you specified what OS you are running. And since there is really nothing wrong I think you can get better answers other places.

Comment: Those commands will update the libraries and potentially break my code as mentioned in the question.

Comment: If your code gets "broken" when you update update a library on the computer, chances are that your code was buggy. Fix the error and rebuild. You can limit the apt get upgrade to only git, but it will still pull in dependencies for git, so you can still have breakages in our program.

Comment: `apt-get update && apt-get install git` will update just git. (Assuming you're using raspbian which you don't explicitly say.) p.s. Then don't search on upgrading git, just search about how to upgrade a single package.